# How I can call javascript function and get the return value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, android

I want to get the value from my JS function on my Java Android

Sample,

```
function getStringToMyAndroid(stringFromAndroid){
   var myJsString = "Hello World" + ;
   return myJsString;
}
```

Now I want calling function **getStringToMyAndroid("This string from android")** and get the returning **myJsString** on my Android, so I can use **myJsString** later on my Android;

I know I can use

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:getStringToMyAndroid('This string from android')")
```

to call the JS function but I want to get the string or value from JS function

NOTE: My android running on minimum SDK Android 3.0 honeycomb

Comment: What version of Android are your targeting?

Comment: Hi @RGraham I'm using minimum Android target is API 11 Android 3.0 Honeycomb, thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For API Level < 19 there are only workarounds of either using a JavascriptInterface (my preferred method, below) or else hijacking the OnJsAlert method and using the `alert()` dialog instead. That then means you can't use the `alert()` function for its intended purpose.

**View:**

```
WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "AndroidApp");
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:doStringToMyAndroid('This string from android')")
```

**JsInterface:**

```
public class JsInterface() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    void receiveString(String value) {
        // String received from WebView
        Log.d("MyApp", value);
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function doStringToMyAndroid(stringFromAndroid){
   var myJsString = "Hello World" + ;
   // Call the JavascriptInterface instead of returning the value
   window.AndroidApp.receiveString(myJsString);
}
```

But on API Level 19+, we now have the evaluateJavascript method:

```
WebView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return getStringToMyAndroid('" + myJsString + "'); })();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("LogName", s); // Returns the value from the function
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code and explanation, I have one question is doStringToMyAndroid is function from JS?? WebView.loadUrl("doStringToMyAndroid('This string from android')"), thanks I will try now :)

Comment: @ilovebali Sorry, yes that's a Javascript function. Replacement for your `getStringToMyAndroid` - I've updated the code to make that clearer

Comment: I tried your code and no luck yet :(, I tried also use the last code that make my app crash :), what I do is I created new java class from JsInterface and called it from my webView `WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "AndroidApp");
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:doStringToMyAndroid('This string from android')")`, need advise, thanks :)

Comment: Have you set [WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean))

Comment: On your class `public class JsInterface() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    void receiveString(String value) {
        // String received from WebView
        Log.d("MyApp", value);
    }
}` you have **"()"** after class name, on mine is I remove it, because I got Error:(9, 25) error: '{' expected, then I remove the **"()"** from class name, I got no error but the code is not working, thanks :)

Comment: Now the code is working perfectly, It was my bad, I put wrong webView so the code can not get the right webView, thanks for your help :D

Comment: @RGraham, I am using API 16 in AVD, So I used your answer for API level <19. In my LogCat there is no message prints as it was in JSInterface class [Log.d("MyApp", value);].. Is there any thing I need to do?